# Consolibyte quickbooks-php fatal error: Redefinition of parameter $action

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Our php code for connecting to QuickBooks Online has been working great for about six months with no obvious errors.

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 we are suddenly seeing errors like this:

`PHP Fatal error:  Redefinition of parameter $action in /quickbooks-php/QuickBooks/Callbacks.php on line 587`

Before I waste time chasing this down I'm hoping someone recognizes this error.

Comment: Check your version, you might need to update, looks as if some stuff has been commented out https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/QuickBooks/Callbacks.php#L586

Comment: Yes, that was it. We grabbed the newest github code and the problem went away. Still testing to be sure nothing new is broken, but so far so good.

Answer (score -2):

This is because not all the old versions of QuickBooks support PHP7. You upgraded your system and PHP got upgraded to 7.x version.